# Как расставить запятые в указанном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите расставить запятые в предложении:

**Временно по техническим причинам при онлайн оплате заказа на сайте банковской картой скидка 20% не действует.**

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предложила сформулировать иначе - в вашем варианте черт ногу сломит:)

"При оплате заказа банковской картой на сайте 20%-ная скидка временно не действует по техническим причинам".

Если решите оставить свой - запятые в нем не нужны.

Answer (score 0):

**Временно (по техническим причинам) при онлайн оплате заказа на сайте банковской картой скидка 20% не действует.**

Обстоятельства "временно по техническим причинам" нельзя считать  неоднородными (они связаны по смыслу, второе объясняет первое), да и вообще при таком стечении второстепенных членов содержание предложения понимается  с трудом. Поэтому желательно применить обособление, лучше скобками (такой вариант легче читается).